# MTBF / MTTF and parallel systems

Tags: reliability, component-failure, failure-analysis

I'm doing an MTBF calculation for a system. Basically I calculated or searched for the MTBFs / FITs of every component. Then added up the FITs and got the total MTBF.

My first question would be the following: in many calculations and handbook (217F), only FIT ie. MTBF values are accessible. In case on a non-repairable system such as mine, can I safely assume that MTTF = MTBF?

My second question revolves around an example.

Now I some components are parallel, and I'm not sure how to compute the FIT for it. 
Anyhow, let's assume components (let's say they are resistors) A and B are in parallel (let's assume they share the same load in normal operation) the system fails only if A and B fail at the same time. 
I would like to write this but I'm not certain:

MTBF(system) = MTTF(system) = 1/FIT(A) + 1/FIT(B) - 1/(FIT(A) + FIT(B))
             = 3/ (2*FIT(A))

I'm basing this calculation on this  [link](https://sars.org.uk/BOK/Applied%20R&M%20Manual%20for%20Defence%20Systems%20(GR-77)/p4c06.pdf) pages 15-16.

Is this calculation correct?

Answer (score 2):

> My first question would be the following: in many calculations and
>   handbook (217F), only FIT ie. MTBF values are accessible. In case on a
>   non-repairable system such as mine, can I safely assume that MTTF =
>   MTBF?

[MTBF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures) = MTTF + MTTR : -

[image]

Realistically, what most people mean when they say "MTBF" is "mean time to fail" (MTTF). So, you can't reasonably and safely assume anything. You can't assume MTTR is zero but many people do.

> let's assume components (let's say they are resistors) A and B are in
>   parallel (let's assume they share the same load in normal operation)
>   the system fails only if A and B fail at the same time. I would like
>   to write this but I'm not certain

You need to decide whether it's possible to repair resistor A while resistor B is still working (i.e. the system is not suffering down time). You also need to decide if resistor A failing is self revealing and, if it is you also have to factor-in the reliability of the circuit that reveals resistor A or B failing. See [MTBF and MDT for networks of components in the same wiki page as above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_time_between_failures#MTBF_and_MDT_for_networks_of_components).

Comment: hehehe I can improve MTBF by shutting down the repair shop!

Comment: @BrianDrummond correct LOL

Comment: thanks! Yeah my resistors cannot be repaired, it's not being detected if a resistor fails, so if only one fails it continues to work

Comment: @Andyaka would you say my calculation above is correct (I have a non repairable system)?

Comment: It's more complex than that... The probability of a device surviving the time implied by it's MTBF is 37%. this means that the probability of it failing is 63%. It's an exponential relationship by the way. The probability of two independent devices failing is reduced by 50% of 63% to 31.5%. This means the probability of one of two independent devices reaching their respective MTBFs is improved from one device (37%) to two devices (68.5%) i.e. nearly statistically doubled. [Useful paper](https://ftp.automationdirect.com/pub/Product%20Reliability%20and%20MTBF.pdf) read page 3 specifically.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks a lot, that's a very interesting article, summarizing the concept quite well indeed!